# What type of browser is called on WebView in Xamarin.macOS?

Tags: browser, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.mac

I'm creating a Mac App with Xamarin.Forms. I have the cross platform project in which i have a mainpage with the webview and a cocoa mac project as the entry point of the application.
i'm trying to open in the webview pages as gmail or what's app web but the browser inside seems to be unsupported:

Below the code and a screenshot.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid
    BackgroundColor="Aqua">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout
                Grid.Column="0"
                Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    x:Name="WhatsAppButton"
                    Source="whatsapp.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="WhatsAppButton_OnClicked"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <WebView
            x:Name="MainWebView"
            Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void WhatsAppButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var webViewSource = new UrlWebViewSource();
    webViewSource.Url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/";
    this.MainWebView.Source = webViewSource;
}
```

The image below as the result:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO0BV.png)

Is there a way to use a newer browser within the webview, if that's the case?

Comment: it's a WebKit.WebView.  You can try modifying the UserAgent string to fool gmail into thinking you're using a supported browser

Comment: thanks Jason. i've figured out what you told me by implementing a custom renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to edit the default user agent by defining a custom renderer that inherits from WkWebView. WkWebView has a property named CustomUserAgent that is just what i needed.

So this is the custom renderer:

```
using Foundation;
using SuperWrapper.CustomRenderers;
using SuperWrapper.macOS.CustomRenderers;
using WebKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(SuperWebView), typeof(SuperWebViewRenderer))]
namespace SuperWrapper.macOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class SuperWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<SuperWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        private WKWebView _wkWebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SuperWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                this._wkWebView = new WKWebView(this.Frame, config);
                this.SetNativeControl(this._wkWebView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var source = (UrlWebViewSource) e.NewElement.Source;
                if(source != null)
                    this.Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(source.Url)));
                this.Control.CustomUserAgent = e.NewElement.UserAgent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this the custom class with the "overriding" property:

```
public class SuperWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UserAgentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "UserAgent",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(SuperWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string UserAgent
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(UserAgentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserAgentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

For my purpose i found what user agent there was on Safari e paste it in UserAgent property.

```
<customRenderers:SuperWebView
            x:Name="MainWebView"
            Source="https://web.whatsapp.com/"
            UserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36"
            Grid.Column="1"/>
```